# Sending emails on behalf of site users

Tags: node.js, email, security, session, nodemailer

*Edited title: Sending emails on behalf of site users without identity reveling (preferably and not necessarily)*

In the hope of making a useful website and as users value privacy, I want to make the service accessible and useful without any form of sign up. Also I don't want to deal with a heavy user sessions system and setting a **messaging service**.

For the sign up and user session, it's done, I set it all working great without any requirement of user information except the email (**passwordless**).

Now to offer messaging between user I don't want to implement a **messaging system**. I just want the web server to act as a relay (How do you call this: **Email proxy**?), where one user can sign up (with their email) and be able to send a message to other users without knowing their email, just replying to their posts by messaging (not comments).

It is easy to send his message to someone else using "admin" email, It would be like this:

`sender@email.com ==> admin@email.com ==> reciever@email.com`

But, I need to save in a session the sender's email and wait for a response to send it back!!!

Now, what are the possible drawbacks of this ? Do I need to implement this simple scheme ? Although I feel like there are better ways. At least, I used Craigslist once and I believe they send an email to the receiver but with there kind-of **one time email** like `98F4EZ984FZ98F4Z@craigslist.com` then the receiver can respond and the message is sent back (how automatically though ?).

I am using **Node.js** as a back-end web server.

Comment: Apparently there is the option of `Reply-To` implemented in nodemailer. So I can put the "sender's" email. Also a `Message-ID` that can be the targeted post

Comment: There is a huge chance that you will act as a relay for spammers and scam artists here. I would not rely on mail for your internal messaging.

Comment: but an email can only be sent from someone logged in, at least he (even a spammer) has an email I think this eliminates 90% of spammers right ?

Comment: coupled with say thehoneypot project and other spam databases.